# Disabling validation controls when using a LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I am using a LinkButton to trigger an email template. When the LinkButton is clicked, I need to disable all field validation controls

I tried the causesvalidation property, but the validations are still triggered.

How can I do this in c# / asp.net?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I don't think you need to disable the validations controls. I assume that you have another button on the page that fires all validation but you just want to skip them for this button.

Use `CauseValidation = false` on your LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server"
  Text="Generate Template" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:LinkButton >
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: for some reason I had to shut down VS 2008 and restart it and it worked. Thanks Claudio!

Answer (score 1):

Set the OnClick attribute of the LinkButton to a method you create that disables the controls.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="btnLinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
protected void btnLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    control1.Enabled = false;
    control2.Enabled = false;
}
```

mileage will vary when disabling your validation controls, but this would work if you were using the generic .NET validation controls.